# Erro ao publicar na Play Store (No momento, o nível desejado da API do seu app é 28.)

Tags: flutter

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao tentar publicar meu App

> No momento, o nível desejado da API do seu app é 28. No entanto, esse
> nível precisa ser de pelo menos 29

Como alterar o nível do API para 29?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo o [guia da Google](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) (com [este](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859152?visit_id=637402290138888882-3955953468&rd=1#targetsdk) link no primeiro parágrafo) você precisa modificar a propriedade `targetSdkVersion` de seu aplicativo:

> Todo APK tem um targetSdkVersion no arquivo de manifesto, também conhecido como o nível desejado da API. Essa versão informa como seu app é executado em diferentes versões do Android.

Para fazer isso, os seguintes passos:

- Acesse o arquivo `build.gradle` localizado em: `NomeDeSeuProjeto/android/app/build.gradle`.
- Localize o seguinte bloco de código:

```
defaultConfig {
       // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
       applicationId "SeuAppId"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 28 // Modifique aqui o valor desejado para 29
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVersionName
   }
```

- Altere a propriedade especificada para o valor de 29. (Comentário no bloco acima.)

Comment: `Também é necessário verificar quaisquer restrições que possam existir na versão da Biblioteca de Suporte do Android que você está usando. Como sempre, é preciso garantir a compatibilidade entre.....e o compileSdkVersion do app.` Será que devo mudar também `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: Para o erro em questão, não precisa. Essa parte mais abaixo no guia é para a migração de um aplicativo antigo para uma versão mais nova. Essa "Biblioteca de suporte do Android" é uma biblioteca que faz seu aplicativo dar suporte às versões mais antigas de Android. Logo, ela deve estar alinhada com a versão de Android que você está usando para compilar o seu código, o que já é verdade. [Essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629181/10746978) resposta explica bem a diferença entre as versões. Também editei a resposta para incluir mais um link.